# How to update the dependent values in a table when the main table is altered?

Tags: mysql

I have a main table which has lot of dependent tables associated with it. In the example below I update the values in main table in column `RollNo` when a value in it has `BCC` in it.

```
   Main Table                  Table 1                    Table 2

ID   NAME   RollNo        RollNo  Col1  Col2             Id Col3 Col4              
1    A      BCC1          BCC1    AAA   BBB              3  CCC  DDD
2    A      B2            BCC3    EEE   FFF              5  GGG  HHH
3    C      BCC3          C3      III   JJJ  
4    D      XYZ
5    C      C3
```

In Main Table, I update values "BCC1" and "BCC3" to "B2" and "C3" respectively (I don't need any values with "BCC' in them").
My questions:
1. How do I update `Table1.RollNo` values?
2. I need to change `Table2.Id` value 3 -> 5. How do I go about it?
Eventually my plan is to delete all the rows in main table which has `BCC` under `RollNo` column.
I'm not necessarily looking for code but any idea on how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're talking about cascading updates. Are your dependent tables linked to your main table with proper foreign keys? Cascading updates are properties of the foreign keys.

Comment: Some tables are linked with foreign keys and some are not. There are approximately 15 tables dependent on main table.

Answer (score 0):

Define the foreign keys as `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE.`